# Is it possible to load data into a table using just SQL on Databricks?

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm familiar with Python on Databricks to load data into a directory like `df.write.format('delta').save('/dir/to/output/')`

Is there a SQL-like equivalent of that? I can't find any documentation that mentions it like a `select into` or just any similar ability to write data onto a directory or table.

Would appreciate any tips!

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think you are just looking for an [`INSERT` statement](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use something like

INSERT INTO table_name PARTITION (id = 1234) SELECT name, address FROM persons WHERE name = "ABC";

this is the sql format you should be using as per link [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of achieving it:

- using `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT ... FROM ...` as pointed by @NNM or with `TABLE ...` ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html)).  Please note that `INSERT INTO` supports [direct load into the directory](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html#insert-into-a-directory).
- for some source data formats, like, Parquet, CSV, ... you can use `COPY INTO` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html)) that provides idempotent data loading, guaranteeing that you won't reprocess already processed files.
- if you need to do complex data loading with updates and maybe deletes, not only with inserts, you can use `MERGE INTO` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html))